# clear as line break

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to use `clear` like line break e.g.:

```
<form action="test.html">
    <label for="name">What is your name?</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
</form>

input {
    clear: left;
}
```

Or it used only with floats? 
If not what is the best way to break the line befor input in above example? (`p`, `input {display: block;}` or smth else?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to W3C XHTML Standards, you are **not** supposed to put `<label>` and `<input />` tags directly inside `<form>`. So, either you can move them inside a `<div>`, this way:

```
<form action="test.html">
    <div><label for="name">What is your name?</label></div>
    <div><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></div>
</form>
```

Or, more semantically,

```
<form action="test.html">
  <ul>
    <li><label for="name">What is your name?</label></li>
    <li><input type="text" id="name" name="name"></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

And style the `<ul>` and `<li>`. Or if you prefer not to change the markup, you can give a style the `label` or `input` to be block.

```
label, input {display: block;}
```

Comment: Long time I didn't read the spec but if no mistake you can also wrap them in p tags.

Comment: You cannot have any other tags other than formatting tags inside `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Set `label` to `display: block`. No markup change, only CSS.